Keygen sh cloud platform zapier automation invalid uuid
I’m trying to automate licensing with keygen sh with stripe using Zapier. When I made a payment I am getting 400 badway error keygen sh create licence node.
When I am checking the logs on keygen sh side it has written the id is a string not uuid string. Following json is the error body.
{
  "meta": {
    "id": "5ac0f653-4351-415c-aa0d-7661c8da256e"
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "title": "Bad request",
      "detail": "type mismatch (received string expected UUID string)",
      "source": {
        "pointer": "/data/relationships/owner/data/id"
      }
    }
  ]
}

